# Should I weight paint a character's jacket or use cloth modifier

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a character that is wearing a jacket. I wish to pose him for still renders. Because I want him to bend over, reach high and be in wind, I want the jacket to respond to gravity.

If I weight paint, it deforms with him and hugs the body. I use a cloth modifier, then pose him, the jacket falls to ground.

I have tried weight painting the sleeve and collar and pinned to character's shirt in T pose, then posed him and the jacket remains in T pose and when animation starts it falls to ground.

Is there a method of attaching a jacket, with cloth modifier so that it follows the character's pose, and remains with him to obtain the natural look?

Thanks in advance for any advice. I am clearly not approaching this right.